# The named parameter "backgroundColor" is not defined error in ElevatedButton.styleFrom

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, background-color, flutter-engine

The named parameter "backgroundColor" is not defined error in ElevatedButton.styleFrom

Getting error in flutter code. Elevated button error. How to make supported elevated button backgroundColor or disabledForegroundColor.

[image]

Comment: Can you include your flutter verison

Comment: Flutter 3.5.0-10.0.pre.156 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d48e6a3fb7 (8 hours ago) • 2022-10-29 02:07:28 -0400
Engine • revision b5fa76b52b
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-350.0.dev) • DevTools 2.18.0

Comment: I updated flutter version and the error gone. But now the following error is occuring.

C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to stable version `3.3.x`, your version is `Flutter 3.5.0-10.0.pre`.

You can try `flutter channel stable` , then `flutter upgrade`

Comment: Alhamdulillah... Solved the problem by upgrading flutter version and firebase core 1.24.0